# Visualforce Error - Dynamic SOQL Binding

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

I have queried Account record using dynamic SOQL

```
<apex:PageBlockTable id="tableid" value="{!lstAccount}" var="acc">
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstField}"  var="f">
        <apex:column value="{!acc[f]}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:PageBlockTable>
```

**Visualforce Error :**

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesDeveloperException: Data type not supported: Address
```

Comment: BillingAddress and ShippingAddress are Compound Fields, which can not be accessed from `apex:column`. See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_limitations.htm) for Compound Field Limitations, which suggests to  _"Use the individual field components to access or update field values."_

Comment: I want to show only one record on my VF page, like we see on detail Page, How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Or anything else, which I can use Instead of <Apex:column> in there ? I have tried <apex:outputField> <apex:outputLable> but it shows me a Blank Page.

Comment: As mentioned above: _"Use the individual field components to access or update field values."_ ie instead of using `BillingAddress`, which is the compound field, you would use `BillingCity`, `BillingCountry`, `BillingPostalCode`, `BillingState` and `BillingStreet`

Comment: I have queried that fields using "Dynamic Binding", So i want to show all of the fields on VF page. "Visualforce Dynamic Binding"